# Should I use is or are below?

Tags: grammar

Below should I say "is" or "are"?

When we talk about structures, the first thing that comes to our minds is the buildings

Answer (score 0):

**the first thing** that comes to our minds **is** the buildings.
your sentence is correct, subject is singular. for example:
one of the most importance things **is** ....
**the first things** that comes to our minds **are** the buildings.